# SQLite Error Code near "IS"

Tags: java, android, mysql, sqlite

I'm breaking a rule while creating my SQLite database table and I'm unsure how to fix this issue.

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_ALARMS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ALARMS + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_BLOCKED_NUMBER + " TEXT," + KEY_FREQUENCY_GPS + " INTEGER FREQUENCY," + KEY_CLTTL + " INTEGER FREQUENCY, "
                + KEY_ICON + " ICON KEY, " + KEY_RINGTONE + " RINGTONE KEY," + KEY_ALARM_SENSITIVITY + " INTEGER SENSITIVITY," + KEY_SMSTTL + " STRING SMSTTL," + KEY_PASSWORD + " TEXT," + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT," + KEY_ARMED + "IS ARMED,"
                + KEY_GPS + " IS GPS," + KEY_NETWORK + " IS NETWORK," + KEY_SMSOPENED + " IS OPENED," + KEY_INVALIDUNLOCK + " IS UNLOCKED," + KEY_DATA + " IS DATA" + ").";

        db.execSQL(CREATE_ALARMS_TABLE);
        Log.i(TAG, CREATE_ALARMS_TABLE);
    }
```

LogCat:

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "IS": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE alarms(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,blocked_number TEXT,frequency_gps INTEGER FREQUENCY,clttl INTEGER FREQUENCY, icon ICON KEY, ringtone RINGTONE KEY,alarm_sensitivity INTEGER SENSITIVITY,smsttl STRING SMSTTL,password TEXT,email TEXT,armedIS ARMED,gps IS GPS,network IS NETWORK,sms_opened IS OPENED,invalid_unlockIS UNLOCKED,data IS DATA,).
```

Comment: you can not have columns names with spaces

Comment: @ScaryWombat Unless you escape the column name with `\`\``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a missing space after `KEY_ARMED`.

But the actual problem is that `IS` is a [keyword](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html), so it must be quoted wherever it occurs:

```
String CREATE_ALARMS_TABLE = "..." + KEY_ARMED + " \"IS\" ARMED,"
        + KEY_GPS + " \"IS\" GPS," + ...;
```

While having multiple, random words in a column type is allowed, it might be a better idea not to use `IS`.

Answer (score 0):

`IS` a keyword in SQL and it's syntactically not valid in a `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Consider the following:

- Use only datatypes understood by sqlite. See http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html
- Have whitespace between column name and its type. For example, `KEY_ARMED + "IS ARMED"` is missing a space.